# Build error using Parse.framework on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sphero-api, parse-framework

I try to use parse.framework in my project, so besides added parse.framework
I added these as well

```
AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
```

since I do use -ObjC linker flag for sphero's RobotKit.framework, I added these two as well

```
Accounts.framework
Social.framework
```

however, I got errors

```
Ld /Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SenseWatch.app/SenseWatch normal armv7
cd /Users/SharpPug/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/SharpPug/Documents/Repo/SenseWatch/Frameworks -filelist /Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Intermediates/SenseWatch.build/Debug-iphoneos/SenseWatch.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SenseWatch.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -lstdc++ -lsqlite3 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework Social -framework Accounts -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework ExternalAccessory -framework CoreMotion -framework RobotKit -framework CoreBluetooth -framework Parse -framework MicrosoftBandKit_iOS -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Intermediates/SenseWatch.build/Debug-iphoneos/SenseWatch.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SenseWatch_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/SharpPug/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SenseWatch-ftxgnedstrsxkufpnnuizgjbgbni/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SenseWatch.app/SenseWatch

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
  ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke226 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke319 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(ParseManager.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFile.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFileManager.o)
  ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTwitterAuthenticationProvider.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(ParseManager.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
  ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFSQLiteDatabase.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFOfflineStore.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
  objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to include the Parse SDK from here:

https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Parse.framework

ParseUI.framework
etc

The easiest (if you're not well into a project) is actually to just start with a quickstart project.

https://parse.com/apps/quickstart

Comment: so, i added parse.framework already. and is the rest like parseUI.framework necessary? And I have a project already

Comment: Well, they're not all necessary, but try with the whole SDK and see if that was the issue. Also try a full clean and build the project.

Comment: Lastly check in your Build Phases -> Link Binary With Files. Add any missing frameworks.